# Google Drive API V3 with PHP client 2.0 - download file contents and metadata in a single request

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to download files from Google Drive using PHP client v2.0 with Drive API V3.

Is it possible to retrieve file's body and metadata in a single HTTP request?

Supplying `'alt=media'` to `->files->get()` returns `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response` upon which I can run `->getBody()->__toString()`.

If I do not provide `'alt=media'`, then `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` is returned that has all the metadata, but does not have body.

**Question.**

Is it possible to get both metadata and body in the same request?

Comment: You can only make it in two separate request. This is due to the `alt=media` being required in order to be able to download the file. There is another way of downloading a file, it is by using `downloadURL` but by using it you will not be able to request for metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
```

//  Look at this first: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

//change to your timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
```

//change scopes to the ones you need

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_APPDATA, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA);
$accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents('credentials.json'), true);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

//Refresh the token if it's expired. Google expires it after an hour so necessary

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents('credentials.json', json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
$fileId = 'yourfileid;
$file = $service->files->get($fileId, array('alt' => 'media'));
file_put_contents("hello.pdf",$file->getBody());
?>
```